# In Ruby, what does a top-level assignment do?

Tags: ruby, global-variables, variable-assignment, toplevel

I have the following code at the top-level of a `.rb` file:

```
class Times
    def initialize(n)
        @n = n               
    end
    def each()        
        (1..@n).each {yield}
    end
end
three_times = Times.new(3)

def f()
    Times.new(3).each {puts 'Test'}
end
f()
```

This works, and prints 'Test' three times, as expected. However, if I replace `Times.new(3)` in `f` with `three_times`, i.e. `three_times.each {puts 'Test'}`, I get an error:

```
`f': undefined local variable or method `three_times' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Why does this not work? Why is `Times` accessible from within `f`, but not `three_times`?

More generally, what exactly does an assignment at the top level (e.g. `three_times = Times.new(3)`) do?

Answer (score 3):

Because

- `three_times` is a local variable
- local variables are only accessible inside of a specific scope
- `def` in ruby creates a new scope

So when f is invoked, it does not see or have access to `three_times`

To access three_times change it to either a global variable `$three_times` or an instance variable `@three_times`

The reason that you are able to reference the class Times is that it is a constant and ruby goes through a separate process of lookup for constants.

---

Sidestepping issue with `def`

You could also access the local variable by using a block to define your method, which sidesteps the whole scope gate issue.  I do this sometimes when writing rake tasks but rarely do it outside of scripts.

```
three_times = Times.new(3)
define_method :foo do
  three_times.each { puts 'Tests'}
end
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this not work? Why is `Times` accessible from within `f`, but not `three_times`?

Variables whose name starts with a lowercase letter are *local variables*. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in (that's why they are called *local* variables.)

Variables whose name starts with an uppercase letter are *constants*. Constants are looked up first in the default constant scope, then lexically outwards, then dynamically upwards by inheritance.

> More generally, what exactly does an assignment at the top level (e.g. `three_times = Times.new(3)`) do?

Nothing special. It does the same thing that an assignment anywhere else does. In this case, it:

1. Dereferences the variable (constant) `Times`, let's call this object **o1**.
2. Evaluates the literal integer expression `3`, let's call the resulting object **o2**.
3. Sends the message `new` to **o1**, passing **o2** as an argument. Let's call the answer to that message send **o3**.
4. Binds **o3** to the local variable named `three_times`.

As you can see, there's nothing in there that is somehow specific to script scope or the top-level.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's looking for a local variable called "three_times". If you wish to make "three_times" to be "top-level" or "global", prepend the variable name with $ so that it's "$three_times".

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, there is no errors. You can call `f()` sucecsfully

Comment: As mentioned, the code stops working if I replace `Times.new(3)` in `f` with `three_times`.